# Mime validation for php file upload not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, oop

I'm trying to validate the mime type of a file before I upload it to the database. However, I'm not getting any output from my program. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance :)

Form handle code (handleUpload.php)

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $Upload = new Upload();
        if (function_exists("check_doc_mime")) {
            //validate MIME type
            $validateMime = $Upload->check_doc_mime($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
           if (!$Upload->check_doc_mime($validateMime)) {
                /* Not a MIME type we want on our site, stop here
                 * and return an error message, or just die(); */
                echo "Mime not what we want.";
            } else {
                echo "This is okay";
            }
        } 
    }
?>
```

Functions and database manipulation code (upload.php)

```php
<?php
    // If it's going to need the database, then it's 
    // probably smart to require it before we start.
    require_once(LIB_PATH . DS . 'database.php');

    class Upload extends DatabaseObject {

        protected static $table_name = "resume";
        protected static $db_fields = array('resume_id', 'individual_id', 'resume_title', 'file_type', 'file_size', 'upload_date', 'status', 'resume_data');
        public $resume_id;
        public $individual_id;
        public $resume_title;
        public $file_type;
        public $file_size;
        public $upload_date;
        public $status;
        public $resume_data; 
        protected $destination; //so cannot be changed outside of class

        function check_doc_mime($tmp_name) {
          // MIME types: http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php
          $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
          $mtype = finfo_file($finfo, $tmp_name);
          if($mtype == ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") || 
            $mtype == ("application/vnd.ms-excel") ||
            $mtype == ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") || 
            $mtype == ("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint") ||
            $mtype == ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation") || 
            $mtype == ("application/pdf")) {
            return TRUE;
          }
          else {
            return FALSE;
          }
          finfo_close($finfo);
        }



        public function uploadResume($fileName, $tmpName, $fileSize, $fileType, $date){

            global $database;

            $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
            $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
            $content = addslashes($content);
            fclose($fp);

            if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
            }
             $sql = "INSERT INTO resume (resume_title, file_size, file_type, resume_data, status, individual_id) ".
                "VALUES ('$title', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content', '1', '$id')";
             $database->query($sql);
        }



    }

    $Upload = new Upload();
    $upload =& $Upload;
?>
```

Comment: I'm new to this and I'm not quite sure what you mean.Is it this? "function(check_doc_mime) {}" on my upload.php. If not, may I please know where to define it?

Comment: @TinyGiant is asking  where you have the function `check_doc_mime` written out. Somewhere, you have the function written out like `function check_doc_mime($var) { code here }`. We need to see what that function does.

Comment: Nevermind, totally missed that it was in the second code block. But it is a method of `Upload`. `$Upload = new $Upload();` should be `$Upload = new Upload();` and `if (!check_doc_mime($validateUser)) {` should be `if (!$Upload->check_doc_mime($validateUser)) {`

Comment: I've added those changes but I'm still not seeing my echo. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out is because I did not write my if statement correctly. It should have been `if (!$validateMime) {` not `if (!$Upload->check_doc_mime($validateMime)) {`.